# transfer data from textbox to textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small problem with my javascript code, im trying make a small application with 2 textboxes and 1 textarea. When textbox 1 is filled in you can press enter and then the focus will go to textbox 2. When textbox 2 is filled then the data from textbox 2 will go automaticly to the textarea as somekind of storage. And i fould like it to work with only plain javascript so it could support all the browsers and older browsers like IE 8

I have a massive javascript and every function works but somehow the big picture doesnt work. Can someone help me figure  out why my javascript isnt doing what i want. And what i want is explained above.

https://jsfiddle.net/LLfwhL3L/2/
I cleaned the fiddle up fith the jshint functions from jsfiddle and get no erros, but it still doesnt work

These are the functions where i think it goes wrong:

```
function AddToList() {
            var bonregel = document.getElementById("bonregel");
            var val = bonregel.value.toString();

            if (val != "") {
                var box = document.getElementById("bonregelbox");
                if (box.value != "")
                    box.value += "\n";
                box.value = box.value + val;
            }
            bonregel.value = "";
            bonregel.focus();
        }

        var delayrec = [];
        function delay(callback, id, calldelay) {
            clearTimeout(delayrec[id]);
            delayrec[id] = setTimeout(callback, calldelay);
        }

        function keyup(event) {
            var locatiebox = document.getElementById("locatie");
            var bonregelbox = document.getElementById("bonregelbox");
            var bonregels = bonregelbox.value.split(/\r\n/).join(",");
            var locatie = locatiebox.value;

            if (event.keyCode == 125)
                SubmitContent(locatie, bonregels);
            else
                delay(AddToList, "AddToList", 500);
        }
```

**The working fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/LLfwhL3L/5/

This is the working fiddle and how it should work, but on my device with IE 8 it doesnt work. The text from textbox 2 isnt goeing into the textaera. How can i solve this?

Comment: *"And i fould like it to work with only plain javascript so it could support all the browsers and older browsers like IE 8"* - This is exactly *why* you use a library, they simplify supporting all browsers in a standardised way.

Comment: Can you tell me were i can find the console? or do you mkean the browser console

Comment: Press F12 for console.

Comment: Yeah i knew that, i tought jsfiddle had one build in

Comment: Your new fiddle has the same errors - try entering text in the first box and hitting enter `ReferenceError: CheckLocation is not defined` - and its because all your methods are out of scope. Change the little dropdown from `onLoad` to `no wrap in <head>`.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand that completly can you axplain a little bit more

Comment: ALright ill update the fiddle ASAP

Comment: For example, there are some VERY obvious typo's. `var delayred = [];` and then `clearTimeout(delayrec[id]);` - that typo is in your fiddle but not in the code you posted.

Comment: @Jamiec Changed the fiddle

Comment: Can you actually load that jsfiddle in IE8? jsfiddle itself does not seem to support such an old browser.

Comment: @Jamiec I think you're right, but how can i test it then because my device had ie8 as browser

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in IE8 for me. https://jsfiddle.net/LLfwhL3L/5/embedded/result/ runs it without the editor (which is what fails in IE8 for me). Its firefox you should be worried about. That really doesnt work and its because handling events is slightly different in FF

Comment: Dayum you mircosoft with yourfancy windows CE, its so hard do programm for outdated versions of IE. I discoverd that its using IE 6

Comment: Do you know a way to test that

Comment: @Jamiec You are right it doesnt work in FireFox